# How to cherry-pick commits for a set of file into new set of files in different folder locations?

Tags: git

I have some changes made in another branch that has different folder structure (but same file name) and I want to cherry-pick changes made to certain files that are not in the same location as the current files.  cherry-pick assumes the files are in the same location. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Cherry pick does not assume the same folder structure. Assuming you file **contents** have not changed drastically, Git is very good at merging appropriately. I just tried it, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I tested, it doesn't work.  Does it depend on how many out of sync the folder structure is? Also keep in mind the set of files to cherry-pick came from a different repo but current repo may not have the info on how the folders were changed.

Comment: The main issue would be how drastically the file contents changed. If the branch you are cherry picking to has the same content for the changed file as the commit prior to the cherry picked commit, there should be no issue at all. Otherwise, it depends on how closely the content matches. Git can figure out if a file is a move/rename based on the similarity of content, but never tracks changes, only content. Therefore, the second sentence in your comment is immaterial.

Answer (score 3):

In order to improve your chances of a successful rename/move detection
you can use `--strategy-option="recursive" --strategy-option="rename-threshold=XX%"`. For more details on values that you can use see [`git diff --find-renames`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) or [`git merge` regarding merge strategy `rename-threshold=`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

The default value is 50%, so try decreasing it, and see if it works.

As I have already mentioned in my comment, Git does not track renames/copies/moves in a commit; it only tracks content. All detection of these changes for merging/cherry-picking/diffing happens after the fact.